# In Itext7, how can i go through a string and see if my current font can display the string correctly?

Tags: java, string, fonts, itext

I want to do the exact same thing as the FontSelector class in itext5 but cannot find the equivalent for it in itext7.

Is there such an equivalent Class in itext7?
Or is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is not `FontSelector` class implemented in iText7, but it is on the roadmap.

Meanwhile, you can use `PdfFont#containsGlyph(char unicode)` to check if a font contains the glyph which corresponds to the passed Unicode value.

Comment: OK, I'll build something using 'PdfFont#containsGlyph(char unicode)' for now until FontSelector is implemented. Thank you !